# Send fcm push notification based on user timezone and get time from DB which user set to get notification in Laravel

Tags: laravel, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel and fcm to send push notification. I've send it successfully. Now the scenario is that i want to send it based on User's timezone and user get notification which he/she will set it from app.

Means that, if user set time 08:00:00 then he/she get notification at that time with their timezone. The time is saved in my DB in `user_profile` table, but i don't have an any idea how to set time for push notification in Laravel.

I've 2 push notification to send to users.

1. Morning notification (Send based on User setted time and with their timezone)
2. Evening notification (Send based on User setted time and with their timezone)

If user set time for Morning notification for 8 am then send it at 8 am with their timezone. For information, I've also saved timezone of user while they register.

Anyone know how to achieve this?

If code required let me know please.

Thanks,

Comment: How is this notification generated - what entity is the producer? Whats the limit on firebase how long can message be in the queue?

Comment: I'll generate two files for both notification and make commands as Laravel provides and then i'll manually fire both command using `php artisan mynotificationame`. Will added both commands in kernel file to make it schedule. Will refer this tutorial: https://appdividend.com/2018/03/01/laravel-cronjob-scheduling-tutorial/

Comment: Thats where you need to take the timezone in count, fire only those notifications that make sense (timezone sake).

Comment: Can i make that logic in `Kernel.php` file?

Comment: Note that I am not an expert in this. I think you need to make a NotificationProducer class that will grab all users, compute what time it is (for their timezone) and send a notification if its near 8am or whatever time. And you schedule this producer thing to run every minute or every 30 minutes depends on you. I will think about this a little more, maybe I will get better idea. Good luck!

Comment: Ok, thank you so much @Kyslik. Will try this to implement!! :) It's hard to implement this for me but will try.